# Expect x to be a non-empty array or dataset

Tags: python, keras

以下のコードを実行すると、エラーが出て詰まってしまいました。
前はちゃんとできていたのですが、学習させる画像を増やして実行したところこのようなエラーが出てきました。

どのように対処すればよろしいでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

---

**実行したコード:**

```
from keras.utils import np_utils
import numpy as np

categories = ["L","M","S"]
nb_classes = len(categories)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = np.load("C:", allow_pickle=True)

X_train = X_train.astype("float") / 255.0
X_test  = X_test.astype("float")  / 255.0

y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
y_test  = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)

model = model.fit(X_train,
                  y_train,
                  epochs=100,
                  batch_size=6,
                  validation_data=(X_test,y_test))
```

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
ValueError     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-0f5758f6f275> in <module>
----> 1 model = model.fit(X_train,
      2                   y_train,
      3                   epochs=100,
      4                   batch_size=1000,
      5                   validation_data=(X_test,y_test))


   1108 
   1109         if logs is None:
-> 1110           raise ValueError('Expect x to be a non-empty array or dataset.')
   1111         epoch_logs = copy.copy(logs)
   1112 

ValueError: Expect x to be a non-empty array or dataset.
```

Comment: `np.load("C:", allow_pickle=True)`がドライブ名だけでファイル名が指定されていないですが、質問時の転記ミスでしょうか？ `X_train`とか`y_train`が有効なデータになっているか、呼び出す前に確認してみてください。

Comment: 実際はファイル名は指定しています。

Comment: ちなみに、今でも画像を減らせば正常に動作するのでしょうか？ それならばそれぞれの場合の`model.fit`呼び出し時の各データの違いを比べてみてください。それから実行したコードとエラーメッセージで`batch_size=`の数値が`6`と`1000`で違っています。別のプログラムを実行したのでは？ あとはこちらの記事 [ValueError: Expect x to be a non-empty array or dataset (Tensor Flow lite model maker on Collab)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63231811/9014308) に承認回答の後から付いた回答が適用できるかも？ `batch_size=`で指定した値と画像の数の関係かもしれませんね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。フォルダをもう一度作り直したら正常に動作しました。アドバイスありがとうございました。